# Make a ViewController scrollable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i was wondering how to make a ViewController (or TTViewController) scrollable, e.g. for long pages?

My first try (make the frame bigger) doesnt work.

```
CGRect appFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, appFrame.size.width, appFrame.size.height + 200);
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your view as a subview in `UIScrollView` and set scrollview's contentSize to fit your large page.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to do this with three20 components?

Comment: Any three20 component inherits from UIView so you can add them to UIScrollView as well